# Asp Mvc 4 : Add Child to new Parent

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, one-to-many

I need some help,

I'll do it simply. I have an object Client that has many Appointments. Something Like:

```
public partial class Client
{ 
    ...
    public virtual IList<Appointment> Appointments{ get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way in asp to create a new client with appointments in same page?

P.S: For now, I can add appointments to an existing customer by passing to a partialview the Client id and using ajax and partialView. But, new clients haven't Id. What I've to do?

**UPDATE : Precisions**

This is what I've in my edit view:

```
<p>
@Ajax.ActionLink("NewMeeting", "NewAppointmentFrm", new { clientId = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "appointmentPopup", OnSuccess = "displayFormInPopup('#appointmentPopup','" + "NewMeeting") + "',600,'auto');" })
</p>
<div style="display:none;width:600px" id="appointmentPopup"></div>
```

In the controler I have

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment()
        {
            Client = GetClientById(clientId)
        };

return PartialView("NewAppointmentFrm", appointment);
```

And by submitted the PartialView (NewAppointmentFrm - Appointments Details), I do :

```
public ActionResult CreateClientAppointment(int clientId, Appointment appointment)
{
    var client = GetClientById(clientId);
    client.Appointments.add(appointment)
    SaveClient(client);
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = candidateId });
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that MVC4 has in mind is each model in its own page.
If you want to add a new model its done in a separate page.
More or less as shown here :
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5

If you try to deviate from that pattern, it's a real pain. 
So, I would suggest to put the client in a view and adding an appointment in a separate view
And let MVC do the rest.

Comment: Now, when I edit a client and want to add an appoitment, I've a PartialView that's open into popup with ajax by passing clientId in routesValues. I want the same process for a new client

Comment: The easiest way would be to split the client view into edit client data and add appointment + adding an option to remove an existing appointment, if they are in a table...

Comment: but what to pass to the partial view? Now I pass the client Id from the edit view and at the submit of the appointment partial view, i do : return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = candidateId }); What to do with new object?

Comment: Sorry. I really fail to understand this last comment. 
Can you list your(relevant) views and actions and which of them are partial. Also, what is the flow of the views?